# Add list values to Treemap in actual order using Java

Tags: java, treemap

I have a list of map objects in the following manner

```
List<Map<String, Object>> insurancePercentageDetails = dao.getinusrancePercentageDetails(age);
```

This gives me the output in the following way.

```
[{Age=42, Rate12=0.40, Rate24=0.63, Rate36=0.86, Rate48=1.12, Rate60=1.39, Rate72=1.67, Rate84=1.98, Rate96=2.31, Rate108=3.30, Rate120=3.84, Rate132=4.40, Rate144=5.00, Rate156=5.62, Rate168=6.28, Rate180=6.97, Rate192=7.34, Rate204=7.74, Rate216=8.15, Rate228=8.07, Rate240=8.33}]
```

My actual target is to have a map in the following sorted order

```
{12=0.4,24=0.63 ....}
```

For this I took a static list

```
private final static List<String> period = new ArrayList<>
                    (Arrays.asList("Rate12","Rate24","Rate36","Rate48","Rate60","Rate72","Rate84","Rate96","Rate108","Rate120",
                            "Rate132","Rate144","Rate156","Rate168","Rate180","Rate192","Rate204","Rate216","Rate228","Rate240"));
```

Then

```
    TreeMap<String, Float> insuranceMatrixMap = new TreeMap<String, Float>();


for(String str : period) {  
            insuranceMatrixMap.put(str.replaceAll("Rate", ""), ((BigDecimal) (BBUtil.getInstance().getValue(insurancePercentageDetails, str))).floatValue());
        }
```

This gives me the output

```
{108=3.3, 12=0.4, 120=3.84, 132=4.4, 144=5.0, 156=5.62, 168=6.28, 180=6.97, 192=7.34, 204=7.74, 216=8.15, 228=8.07, 24=0.63, 240=8.33, 36=0.86, 48=1.12, 60=1.39, 72=1.67, 84=1.98, 96=2.31}
```

Not in sorted order.

TreeMap should keep the keys in the sorted order, Isn't it?

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: It IS in sorted order but according to the ***String*** collation values, not numeric order.  If you want it sorted in numeric order you should change the key to `Integer` or provide a custom Comparator that provides the correct ordering.

Comment: @JimGarrison, you are right. I changed TreeMap<String, Float> insuranceMatrixMap to TreeMap<Integer, Float> insuranceMatrixMap. Please put that in answers. I will accept

Answer (score 1):

You are right that TreeMap will sort based on the keys. 
But in your case the Key is String rather than Integer.

And the result is sorted based on the String Value, i.e. 
"108".compareTo("12") will be negative.

The String comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character. 
You have to use `TreeMap<Integer, Float>` if you want to sort on the Integer value.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort it before loop same this :

```
Collections.sort(period, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final String o1, final String o2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(o1.replaceAll("Rate", ""))
                        .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.replaceAll("Rate", "")));
            }
        });
```

Comment: please check Jim answer. That solution is enough. Thanks for your reply